# Swift 3 Obtain PHImageFileURLKey for photos image

Tags: arrays, swift, completionhandler

I have a photo picker which provides me a PHAsset and I need to obtain the local URL for each of the photos.  So far I'm able to do this with the following code:

```
var selectedPhotos =  [NSURL]()
    selectedPhotos.removeAll()
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.version = .original
    options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
    for index in 0..<savedAssets.count
    {
    let asset = savedAssets[index] as PHAsset
    imgManager.requestImage(
        for: asset,
        targetSize: CGSize(width : 1024, height : 768),
        contentMode: .aspectFill,
        options: options,
        resultHandler: { (image, info) in
            let photoUrl = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as! NSURL
selectedPhotos.append(photoUrl)

print("this is the correct Url", photoUrl, "this is an array of URLs", selectedPhotos)

    }

        )
    }
```

As I've discovered you cannot access var "photoUrl" or the array outside the resultHandler.  I need these URLs in other parts of my program.  How can I use this array in other parts of my app?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this the wrong way.  If I want to use the variable photoUrl in the result handler I can pass it to a function.

```
resultHandler: { (image, info) in
        let photoUrl = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as! NSURL
        saveUrlToArray(photo: photoUrl)
})
```

Then just create a function somewhere else that takes in an NSURL.